# Show that $f(z) =z^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer, is analytic .

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> Show that $f(z) =z^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer, is analytic 
>   Find its derivative.

I tried solving it using Cauchy Riemann equation. But for that, $f(z)$ needs to be separated as $f(z)=u+iv$.

$f(z)=(x+iy)^n$

We can expand this binomially then group the real and imaginary parts and then take their partial derivatives. But that would be a tedious process.

I am not able to split $f(z) =z^n =u+iv$. Please help.

Comment: What is your definition of analytic function?

Comment: You don't need Cauchy Riemann, just find the derivative by definition. I'll even give a hint: you can use the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler than that. If $z_0\in\mathbb C$, then$$z^n=\bigl(z_0+(z-z_0)\bigr)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk{z_0}^{n-k}(z-z_0)^k.$$This expresses $z^n$ as the sum of a power series centered at $z_0$.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos, Firstly, I should say, your answer is great. Then I have a question, that is : can $z_0$ be zero or not. I mean that what is the corresponding series of a polynomial $f(z)=z^n$ generally. thanks.

Comment: Yes, it can be $0$. In that case, the answer is just $z^n$. It is a power series, since it is equal to$$0+0\times z+0\times z^2+\cdots+0\times z^{n-1}+z^n+0\times z^{n+1}+\cdots$$

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos, that' s it. thanks a lot.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos, by the way, is it correct that $0^0=1$? it happens when we put $(z_0=0)^{n-n}$ in that series (i.e., the coefficient of $z^n$).

Comment: In the context of power series, yes, $0^0=1$.

Answer (score 2):

The direct definition of the derivative is straight forward.

$$ \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac {z^n-z_0^n}{z-z_0} =\lim _{z\to z_0} (z^{n-1} +z^{n-2}z_0 +...+z_0^{n-1}) = nz_0^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

An analytic function is a function that is locally given by a convergent power series, so it's trivial. I am assuming you mean, $f$ is differentiable everywhere. In this case, as in the real case, it is  just  matter of evaluating $\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{z^{n}-z^{n}_0}{z-z_0}.$